# Create form where the sent content creates another page that displays it

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm creating a website platform where the users can send ideas and sugestions. The idea is that when the user send its sugestion, it automatically creates a new page that displays it. I'm using Wordpress and it would be good if it could be implemented on Wordpress's PHP semantic. But if it's necessary to use pure PHP, it's ok also.

But how can that be done? Would I have to create a new table in MySQL to store that info, or can Wordpress functions deal with that task?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question is rather broad shall we say.

Comment: Drew, could you give me a light on that, even with its broadness? :)

Comment: Ok, in pure php, the guy logs in, you gather info based on his stuff, and php writes back that extra special html related to him.

Comment: just wondering who the ideas/suggestions text gets sent to? Is it sent to the site admin? Are they visble to everybody on a suggestions page? I would maybe create a custom post type for this? Or even create a new table inside of a plugin to store the data. I think you can download starter plugins to help start off with this.

Comment: @fairydragon, the suggestions are supposed to be sent to the site as the page of a post, and it should be visible to everyone. My biggest struggle is what should I code to make that page be automatically created when the user hits 'Send' on the form. The idea of the custom post type is great and should really work, but how to automate that?

Comment: In that case, I think that may be the best way to go. Quick search on google and there are quite a few tutorials on how to create a new post type, on the page in question, perhaps you could query the database for all the posts which have the custom post type of 'suggestion' or whatever you plan to call it. I took a quick look and there are examples on how to do that here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/

Comment: @fairydragon perfect! So I will create a new post type called 'sugestions',  call the function wp_insert_post() on the form action with the form values and post type on its parameters and redirect the user to the recently created post page. Makes sense, doesn't it? Thanks a lot for the help!